# How to get back to fullscreen in Broken Age on OS X?

Tags: macos, broken-age

On OS X, after switching away from the Broken Age application in fullscreen mode, the game goes windowed and I can't find a way to go back. It is not among the options, neither in the menus. Does anyone know a keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, there is: just press **Alt+Enter**.